# Snowflake ext table with pattern case sensitive

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
create or replace external table table_namewith 
    location = @abc/corpfiles
    pattern = '.folder1/subfolder/..csv$' 
    auto_refresh = true 
    file_format = (Type=CSV,field_optionally_enclosed_by = '"');
```

Above ext table works fine but when file extension is uppercase such as abc.CVS then it doesn’t work. abc.csv works fine. How to account for case sensitivity here. Any help?

Snowflake ext table case sensitive with pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PATTERN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-external-table#syntax) is a regex:

> [ PATTERN = '<regex_pattern>' ]

Thus you should be able to use:

```
pattern = '.folder1/subfolder/..[cC][sS][vV]$'
```

to cover the variants